# How can I check my API usage + limits and edition?

Tags: api, limits, editions

I'd like to see how many API calls I've made within the past 24 hours, as well as my request limit for a given 24-hour period.

How can I do this?

I was able to find [this post](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=integrate_api_rate_limiting.htm), but I couldn't figure out what edition I was using, it was unclear to me how the number of users on an account affected the limits, and it doesn't tell me how many calls I've made.

I was also able to find [this on help.salesforce.com](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gtGmAAI), but it's from 2010, and the page it's talking about appears to no longer exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To see what Edition you use, you can check it on the Browser tab. It's written on the tab tooltip.

And to check the number API calls go to : `Setup > Monitoring > System Overview,` and on the top-right block, you can check this information.

Comment: Is there a way to access this info through the api? Like an API call to SF to find my company's current api usage and limits.

Answer (score 4):

You can get this information from the new Limits Resource (Released in Spring '15)

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/dome_limits.htm